# Is there a proper order to run mysqlcheck commands in for periodic maintenance?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, maintenance

Is there a proper order in whcih to run the various [mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_analyze) commands?

e.g. `CHECK TABLE, REPAIR TABLE, ANALYZE TABLE, OPTIMIZE TABLE` and also `FLUSH TABLES and FLUSH LOGS`.

I wrote this script that I plan to run periodically via cron and just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding the docs and running them in the right order, if any.

```
echo -n 'Checking MySQL tables...'
OUTPUT=$(mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/sys.cnf --all-databases --check 2>&1)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ' SUCCESS.'
else
    echo ' FAIL!'
fi

echo -n 'Analyzing MySQL tables...'
mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/sys.cnf --all-databases --analyze >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ' SUCCESS.'
else
    echo ' FAIL!'
fi

echo -n 'Optimizing MySQL tables...'
mysqlcheck --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/sys.cnf --all-databases --optimize >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ' SUCCESS.'
else
    echo ' FAIL!'
fi

echo -n 'Flushing MySQL tables...'
mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/sys.cnf refresh >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ' SUCCESS.'
    echo 'Flushing MySQL logs... SUCCESS.'
else
    echo ' FAIL!'
    echo 'Flushing MySQL logs... FAIL!'
fi

if [ -z "$OUTPUT" ]; then
    :
else
    echo 'Raw mysqlcheck results...'
    echo "${OUTPUT}"
    echo ' ...DONE.'
fi
```

**EDIT**

I updated the script, removed the `REPAIR TABLE` part because I think that type of stuff should be done manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check and repair and flush tables are not relevant unless you use MyISAM tables. I never use MyISAM tables. I never run `mysqlcheck` directly.

`FLUSH LOGS` is not necessary. It does nothing to help tables.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is not usually needed in the default storage engine, InnoDB. InnoDB will re-use empty extents automatically. Eventually, an InnoDB tablespace might become fragmented, but this doesn't necessarily have any negative effect except for taking extra space. `OPTIMIZE TABLE` rebuilds a tablespace in a defragmented manner, so occasionally I would run it, but not on a schedule. Do it as needed, typically after a bulk data import or bulk delete.

`ANALYZE TABLE` is worthwhile to run periodically. I set up a scheduled job to run this about every 10 days per table. Actually my scheduled job would run every day and randomly choose 10% of tables to analyze. That was probably overly complex, because there's no downside to just running `ANALYZE TABLE` every day on every table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, why is `CHECK TABLE` not relevant for InnoDB? [CHECK TABLE Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html), does it not do anything worthwhile? I noticed I don't see any output referencing my existing InnoDB tables when I run the command.

Comment: Edit: I stand corrected on that last comment, I *do* see output referencing my InnoDB tables.

Comment: InnoDB doesn't normally need checking. It maintains page-level checksums at all times. Only bugs or disk corruption could cause problems, and those usually cause errors and bad effects much sooner, so running CHECK TABLE is only needed for confirmation. I don't run it as a scheduled task.